# Installing ram upgrade and new hard disk after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-8, memory, upgrade

I got a new pc for Christmas. It originally had Windows 8 on it. I'm planning to install a new hard drive and RAM upgrade after the Windows 10 update. but it might tell me to activate windows 10 after it happens. I don't want this to happen. Will it happen if I decide to pursue a RAM upgrade?

Comment: It will require you to activate Windows 10 only if you have never activated Windows 10, even if it does, it takes less then 2" seconds to activate again

Answer (score 0):

the product key of any windows OS is attached to the motherboard. As long as you dont change your motherboard, you can do a RAM upgrade as long as you dont change your motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to activate Windows after making a hardware change?

According to [Activation in Windows 10](https://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10):

> If you upgraded to Windows 10 using the free upgrade offer and then made significant hardware changes to your device, such as replacing the motherboard, Windows 10 might no longer be activated.

However according to [Activating Windows 7: frequently asked questions](https://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activating-windows-faq#1TC=windows-7):

> Maybe. When you make a significant hardware change to your computer, such as upgrading the hard disk and memory at the same time, you might be required to activate Windows again.

Both of these situations apply to the case in which you have already activated Windows before making a hardware change, otherwise you would be required to activate Windows 10 anyway as usual.

Microsoft documentation does not say whether the requirements for Windows reactivation after making a hardware change in Windows 7 have been carried over to also apply to Windows 10, but if they have you might be required to activate Windows again after installing a new hard drive and a RAM upgrade. On the other hand if you are planning to add a new hard drive, but not change the hard drive on which Windows is installed, according to a strict interpretation of the Microsoft documentation you would not be required to activate Windows 10 again. I am basing this interpretation on my reasoning that adding another hard drive that is used only for storing data is not "a significant hardware change to your device".

Upgrading only the RAM is not "a significant hardware change to your device" either in my opinion, so you would not be required to reactivate Windows 10 after upgrading the RAM.

Answer (score -1):

A RAM upgrade does *not* require a re-certification.

A new (replacement) hard disk does require it, as you install again, but according to Microsoft, it happens automatically, if it is the same computer. I didn't try it myself though.

Adding a disk has no need for anything.

Comment: Well, i am adding an additional hard disk alongside the operating system's hard disk, not replacing it all together.

Comment: then there will be no problem at all.